# Grab video thumbnail and show it in a Gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, video-thumbnails

I am developing a module for which i want to show all the user's videos from sd card into a Gridview. I have grabbed video file paths in usual way (Checking if file or directory and save if its a file) in a arraylist and grabbed its bitmap thumbnail with following code:

```
Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(VideoValues.get(position).getAbsolutePath(),
                                        Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Obviously this code runs in a background thread. But the only problem is that the gribview still freezes a lot while scrolling. According to me the main problem is extracting the bitmap from video, which takes a lot of time. Can anyone suggest me a different way to get bitmap from video and how it in a grid ? I have seen the smooth behavior in other apps like Facebook, etc. But I cannot figure out as to how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

please use below method for retrive video thumbnail from video

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)
            throws Throwable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
        try
        {
            mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
            bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Throwable(
                    "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                            + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null)
            {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Its not worth to use. It still slow images, you have used MediaMetadataRetriver which we have used already. We are showing video bitmaps in getView method of BaseAdapter